# Number of unique strings that can be formed by reversing one substring of a string

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a string of lowercase characters, pick substring of any length in it and reverse them. Find the number of possible unique strings.

**Example:**
Input string is : abc

**Possible unique strings:**

```
Substring of length 1:

Reversing a single character results in same original string. 
For example reverse a in abc, gives abc

Substring of length 2:
Reverse ab (substring of length 2) in abc results in bac
Reverse bc (substring of length 2) in abc results in acb

Substring of length 3:
Reverse abc (substring of length 3) in abc recults in cba
```

**So return result as 4**

**Constraints:**

```
length of input string is 1 to 10^5
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(solve("abc"));  // 4
    System.out.println(solve("aaaa")); // 1
}

public static long solve(String s) {
    long result = 0;
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    int n = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            String sub = s.substring(i, j);
            String left = s.substring(0, i);
            String right = s.substring(j);
            String mid = new StringBuilder(sub).reverse().toString();
            set.add(left + mid + right);
        }
    }
    result = set.size();
    return result;
}
```

Here my code takes O(n^3) as I have nested loops and again substring method calls (correct me if i am wrong), I want to solve this in less time complexity also less space.

I have added complete details along with the code which I tried, please provide comments whoever is giving negative votes and trying to close my post.

Comment: please add comments for giving negative votes, so I can improve the question. I already explained everything along with my attempt to solve it.

Comment: I think the formula for the number of permutations is (N)(N-1)/2 + 1 for the original. Then you need to do do the uniqueness check. You might be able to reduce the number of checks by looking for the same digits in the input number, but I don't know how you could prove that.

Comment: @matt that formula is for the number of permutations, but that's not what the question asks. Permutations can be made by swapping elements far away from each other. The OP is only interested in permutations that are made by reversing substrings.

Comment: @k314159 that is permutations of the swapping which is literally what op is doing in his loop. Not permutations of the string. It seems like the swapping permutations is a subset of the actually permutations otherwise you can use the N choose n formula and just generate the permutations.

Comment: If you're talking about permutations then there are N! permutations for a string with unique digits. eg (1, 2, 3, 4). There are (N)(N-1)/2 possible swaps.

Comment: I think you're doing it in N^2. Since you're using set.add() the uniqueness check depends on the type of set, best case it is O(1). Worst case it is O(N) so maybe you need to come up with a better hash function since your strings are a specific subset of strings.

Comment: @matt, I am using substring method multiple times, which itself runs in O(n) where n is the size of the substring.

Comment: Okay, you need to generate N^2 strings. You need to copy the strings, if you call that an N operation then N^3 is the minimum.

Comment: @matt, yes im doing the same in my code, i want to reduce time and space complexity now.

Comment: @Unmitigated, yes O(N^2) if possible below to that.

Comment: @matt It is not necessary to generate all the strings to get the count.

Comment: The title suggests generally what you are trying to do but you need to edit to state your question precisely at the beginning. From what I understand it is something like the following: "Given a string of one or more lowercase letters, determine the number of unique strings that can be formed by reversing substrings of one or more letters".

Comment: Am I correct that the answer is 5 for the string `"aaba"`: 1 each for switching an `'a'` (or `'b'`), `'ab'`, `'ba'`, `'aab'` and `'aaba'`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, that would be 4. Reversing `aaba` produces the same result as reversing `ab`.

Comment: Disaster, sorry, I meant @Unmitigated, thanks, I missed that, but you've answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved in linear time. First, the number of ways to select a substring of length at least 2 to reverse is N choose 2 where `N` is the length of the string. We add `1` for the original string itself, which can be created by reversing any of the `N` substrings of length 1. Next, we remove all duplicate substrings from the count. One substring would cause overcounting if its endpoints have the same character, as reversing it would create the same substring as reversing the substring of length 2 less formed by removing the leftmost and rightmost character. In order to quickly find the number of these substrings, we can count the number of occurrences of each character and subtract out the count choose 2 for each character.

```java
public static long solve(String s) {
    var freq = s.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c, c -> 1, Integer::sum));
    long ans = 1L * s.length() * (s.length() - 1) / 2 + 1;
    for (var v : freq.values()) ans -= 1L * v * (v - 1) / 2;
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain more on `One substring would cause overcounting if its endpoints have the same character, as reversing it would create the same substring as reversing the substring of length 2 less formed by removing the leftmost and rightmost character.` , also `and subtract out the count choose 2 for each character.` and `s.length() * (s.length() - 1) / 2 + 1` what this formula indicates.

Comment: @learner For example, if you have the string "cabc", reversing "ab" is equivalent to reversing "cabc" since the string "cabc" has "c" as both the leftmost and rightmost character. `v * (v - 1) / 2` is the formula for (v choose 2). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: Based on your explanation, `v * (v - 1) / 2` is choosing 2 characters from input string to generate strings. but in my question, I can select 2 characters, 3 characters, 4 characters etc up to n to reverse them. So we need to get all such binomial co-efficients. sorry im missing something to understand how it works.

Comment: @learner It's not selecting two characters to be the substring; it's selecting two indexes with the same character to be the endpoints of the substring.

Comment: Thanks for responding, ` 1L * s.length() * (s.length() - 1) / 2 + 1` what this formula indicates

Comment: @learner That's N choose 2 (for N = length of the string) to get all the possible substrings of length at least 2 to reverse, plus 1 for the original string itself.

Comment: why we are not considering N choose 3, N choose 4 etc till N choose N, sorry for asking many questions

Comment: @learner N choose 2 is choosing two indexes in the string as the endpoints of the substring to reverse. N choose 3 wouldn't really be meaningful.

Comment: The crux of this argument is the way you're removing duplicates. If you have multiple occurrences of a character, v times, a duplicate string will be created each time that character is both end points. So you get v choose 2 again. Is there a proof for that? I get the argument that it causes overcounting, but can we be sure it is the only source of overcounting.

Comment: I was asked during an interview few yrs back, it just came to my mind so trying to solve again.

Comment: @matt We can be sure that any substring with distinct end points will create a different result after reversing it. Let us only consider other substrings with different leftmost and rightmost characters. If we extend a given substring in both directions, we change at least 2 different characters, so we get a different result. If we only extend in one direction, we at least change a character at a different index from before, so there are also no duplicates in this case.